# Como puedo cambiarle el estilo a un input de tipo radio

Tags: html, radio

### Lo que estoy intentando de hacer es como puedo cambiarle los estilos a un input de tipo radio pero no me los cambia

```
<input type="radio" name="Register" id="opcion1"> opcion1
<input type="radio" name="Register" id="opcion2"> opcion2
<input type="radio" name="Register" id="opcion3"> opcion3


input[type=radio]{
height: 1.2rem;
width: 1.2rem;
margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
}

#Register input[type=radio]:checked{
background: #1eac66;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero ocultamos el radio option de tipo *radio* predeterminado:

```
.container input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

ahora podemos personalizarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**Ejemplo completo**

```css
/* The container */

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Hide the browser's default radio button */

.container input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Create a custom radio button */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */

.container .checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Personalizar: Radio Buttons</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Fuente: [How TO - Custom Checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)